# Pacemaker failover on service failure without managing the service

Tags: pacemaker, rabbitmq, corosync

I have a rabbit mq ha/cluster, and a virtual ip shared between the two nodes by pacemaker.

The problem is that pacemaker will only failover if the entire active host goes down, but not if rabbit mq goes down on the active host. I can't just add rabbit mq as a resource because pacemaker will stop the service on the passive host, which will stop rabbit mq from syncing messages...

**How do I make the virtual ip failover if rabbit mq goes down on the active host?**

(I'm traveling, so I had to fill this out on my phone. I apologize for any typos.)